# How do I allow only admin to be able to delete/edit users informations using laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I have a dashboard in which I have multiple users, I would like the only admin to be able to edit or delete user information, the normal user should be able to edit/delete his account.

Here is what I have tried so far

Middleware for admin

```
use Closure;
use Auth;
class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Here is users.index table body where I display the data

```
 <tbody>
  @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{ $user->name }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $user->email }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $user->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}
      </td>
      <td class="td-actions text-right">
        @if ($user->is_admin != auth()->id())
          <form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $user) }}" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('delete')

              <a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-link" href="{{ route('user.edit', $user) }}" data-original-title="" title="">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
              </a>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-link" data-original-title="" title="" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this user?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
                  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                  <div class="ripple-container"></div>
              </button>
          </form>
        @else
          <a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-link" href="{{ route('profile.edit') }}" data-original-title="" title="">
            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
          </a>
        @endif
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Data from table looks like this

```
 #original: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "Royaladd"
        "email" => "kaczkapojebana@gmail.com"
        "email_verified_at" => null
        "password" => "$2y$10$3SIVxXu/SyF0vdavnV.DTOcljEqlhAH5J6LV.KmCezdQ4XA11N5m."
        "remember_token" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-02-12 10:36:40"
        "updated_at" => "2020-02-12 10:36:40"
        "is_admin" => 0
      ]
```

Unfortunately the above solution any user can edit or delete user pieces of information.

What do I need to do achieve what I want?

Comment: Surely the test should simply be `@if ($user->is_admin)`

Comment: you are comparing wrong, is_admin and auth id are different. 
just use is_admin or with true or 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly ur solution now normal user can edit or delete admin account , not his account :(

Comment: SO what does `var_dump($user->is_admin)` show, please add to question

Comment: the problem is , $user->is_admin is for each record in loop, you need to get the logged in user is_admin check,

Comment: @AhmedSunny how do I do That?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how are you setting auth and user 
Normally when a user logins, you the auth function only set user basic info and if he is logged in or not.

i assume you have is_admin as  a column is user table.

In your user model you need to have a function to check if user is admin or not
you have Auth::id() which contains user id, and then check from query if this user id is admin or no and return that as true false

```
public function isAdmin() {
   $user= App\user::find(Auth::id());
   // you can also put it in session
   // this session line can add in handle function and call $user->is_admin()
   $this->request->session()->put('is_admin', $user->is_admin); 
   return $user->is_admin; // you can add if check to return true false if you want
}
```

and in your view

```
 @if ($user->is_admin()){
   // everything here is only accessible if its true
 }
```

PS. there could be code errors, just take the logic

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your have role column or attribute in database users table. Create a Midlleware like this

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthMiddleware
```

Then

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
      return $next($request);
    }

      return redirect('home');
}
```

In your kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class,
```

Protect your route

```
Route::get('admin/profile/{id}/delete', function () {
//
})->middleware('admin');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: and on users.index?

Comment: @user9964622 On users.index  Route::get('admin/profile/index', function () {
//
});

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->is_admin == 1) {
        return $next($request);
 }
```

You are checking `Auth::user->admin == 1` please change this condition to `Auth::user()->is_admin == 1` as per your `Auth::user()` data

Comment: and what about users.index?

Answer (score 0):

In your web routes apply your admin middleware to your user delete and edit routes by wrapping it in a middleware group.

```
// -- admin --
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
```

This means that only admins can access those routes otherwise the user will be redirected. You could then edit your admin middleware to accept the request if the authenticated user is the same as the user you're passing into the route?